# Display Images from JSON Array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, image, filepath

I tried to display an image from the image folder in JSON array to Javascript but I am not sure if I am getting the right path.
When the click event happens, everything works except for the image is not showing in the <img id "picture">, the picture is not showing up in the img section of my HTML.

I tried to change the path to ../Images/room_1.jpg but it still not working.

FYI: I have a separate folder that stores images, both json and js are stored in the javascript folder. should I put the same image file in the javascript folder?

html

```
<h2>Select a Hotel</h2>
    <ul class ="hotels">
        <li><a href="#" id="marriott"> Marriott Hotel Rooms</a></li>
    </ul>
<h2 id="hotelName">Hotel</h2>
<h3>Adress: <span id="address"></span></h3>
<img id="picture">
```

Hotel.json

```
{
"hotels": [
    {
        "name": "Marriott",
        "address": "098 hollywood Street",
        "picture": "room_1.jpg"
    }
```

JS

```
async function getHotelData() {

    try {

        const response = await fetch('Javascript//hotel.json')
        return await response.json() 

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }

}

let hotelData = {}

getHotelData().then(data => hotelData = data)
 

const hotelEvent = document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(a => {
    a.addEventListener('click', hotelInfo )
})

function hotelInfo(event) {
    let hotelChoice = hotelData.hotels.find(hotel => {
        return event.target.id === hotel.name.toLowerCase()
        return event.target.id === hotel.address.toLowerCase()
        return event.target.id === hotel.picture.toLowerCase()

        
    })
    console.log(hotelChoice)

    document.querySelector("#hotelName").textContent = `${hotelChoice.name} Hotel`
    document.querySelector("#address").textContent = `${hotelChoice.address}`
    document.querySelector("#picture").innerHTML = `${hotelChoice.picture}`



}
```

Comment: Is the image path inside the JSON file relative the to HTML file? If not, it should be in order to make it work as the image is loaded by the HTML (kinda) and not by the JavaScript.

Comment: @nickfla1 what do you mean by relatives? do I need to add like an src tag in the HTML to make it work?

Comment: I'll try to articulate better in an answer, soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [src property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-src) to the image instead of setting its `innerHTML`.

A normal `img` tag would look something like this:

```html
<img id="image" src="/path/to/image.png">
```

You need to replicate the same using JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector("#picture").innerHTML = `${hotelChoice.picture}`
// Becomes
document.querySelector("#picture").src = `${hotelChoice.picture}`
```

Also, pay attention to the image path inside the JSON file, it should be relative to the HTML document you're using it, not the JavaScript one. So if your images are stored inside a separate directory you should change the path inside your JSON file accordingly.

Example:
If your HTML file is in the project root and there is an `images` folder, you JSON should be something like:

```json
{
  "hotels": [
    {
      "name": "Something",
      "address": "Some Street, 12",
      "picture": "images/picture_name.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: the SRC tag is working !!! thank you so much!

Comment: I can't believe it's just a simple fix